# Is there any supported way for a firebase service accounts to write to your cloud storage buckets?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-storage

As a contrived example:

1. User uploads photo
2. Server transforms that photo into thumbnail, medium, high definition and writes the files to the users directory.

Similar to [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/storage/package-summary) API but for the [server](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/serverreference/packages) module:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since Firebase Storage is backed by Google Cloud Storage, we recommend using Google Cloud Storage through [gcloud-node](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gcloud-node) for this:

```js
// Import gcloud
var gcloud = require('gcloud');
    
// Initialize with a service account
var gcs = gcloud.storage({
  projectId: 'my-project',
  keyFilename: '/path/to/keyfile.json'
});

// Reference an existing bucket.
var bucket = gcs.bucket('<projectid>.appspot.com');

// Upload a local file to a new file to be created in your bucket.
bucket.upload('/photos/zoo/zebra.jpg', function(err, file) {
  if (!err) {
    // "zebra.jpg" is now in your bucket.
  }
});

// Download a file from your bucket.
bucket.file('giraffe.jpg').download({
  destination: '/photos/zoo/giraffe.jpg'
}, function(err) {});
```

There are other gcloud modules for Python, Java, go, ruby, etc. [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gcloud-common).