# Upload image to Firebase Storage from django models in FileField

Tags: django, firebase, firebase-storage

I need to upload an image to Firebase Storage, I'm thinking do it with post_save signal or with the save method. But since Firebase is pure JS, how can I do it in the models.py? Here is the reference of how upload with Firebase Web:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/upload-files

Comment: See the last comment in Mike's answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38521949/is-there-any-supported-way-for-a-firebase-service-accounts-to-write-to-your-clou/38532457#38532457

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're going to want to use [google-cloud-storage](https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-python/latest/#cloud-storage) for this:

```py
# Import
from google.cloud import storage

# Initialize
client = storage.Client()
bucket = client.get_bucket('bucket-id-here')

# Download
blob = bucket.get_blob('remote/path/to/file.txt')
print(blob.download_as_string())

# Upload
blob2 = bucket.blob('remote/path/storage.txt')
blob2.upload_from_filename(filename='/local/path.txt')
```